# PHP if/else structure in WordPress template file doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

Question about a piece of PHP code in a WordPress template file.

The template contains this code:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

I want the title only be printed if the title is not "Home".

But this code doesn't work:

```
<?php if (the_title()!='Home'); ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you should be more clear about the problem than simply saying it "doesn't work". Tell us the error messages you're getting, or what you're seeing that is wrong.

Comment: You're right, will do that the next time, as I normally do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) echoes, it doesn't return its title.

Use [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead.

```
<?php if (get_the_title() != 'Home'): ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As an aside, it looks like you're trying to detect if you're on the home page. Checking against a title can be flaky, as that can change.

Use [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) instead.

```
<?php if ( ! is_home()): ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: +1 for a very helpful answer with lots of wordpress specifics. But you did neglect to point out the one big problem in his PHP syntax (ie the `;` instead of a `:` on the `if()` line).

Comment: Thanks guys, this works. I love SO!! And you are right about detecting the home page. Unfortunately `is_home()` does not work for me. I set this page as "homepage" in the menu by Settings > Reading Settings > Front page displays. But no problem, text will not change and the website has to be finished by today...

Comment: Thanks to @WordpressJoomlafreelancer I changed the code to this: `<?php if (!is_front_page()): ?> <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

`<?php if (the_title()!='Home'): ?>`

```
                              ^
```

Use `:` instead of `;`

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: +1 for spotting the main reason it doesn't run at all. @alex's answer is more complete and more helpful wrt wordpress specifics, but he did neglect to point out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution:

```
<?php if (the_title()!='Home') { ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This won't work - as Alex says, the_title() cannot be evaluated like that, you'd have to use get_the_title().

Comment: ok use get_the_title() with this solution and this won't work?

Comment: No, what I mean is that what you've put will work assuming you use get_the_title instead :)